# Env error when I try to build the application on Render

Tags: node.js, deployment, environment-variables, backend

I am trying to build my application on Render and I am getting this error in the console:

```
    Oct 27 12:54:28 PM  Invalid environment variables { _errors: [], DATABASE_URL: { _errors: [ 'Required' ] } }
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM  Invalid environment variables
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM  Error: Invalid environment variables
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at <anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/src/env/index.ts:22:9)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/src/env/index.ts:25:25)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at Object.j (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/tsx/dist/cjs/index.cjs:1:1197)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at setupKnex (/opt/render/project/src/src/database.ts:3:21)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/src/database.ts:20:37)
Oct 27 12:54:28 PM  ==> Build failed
```

I am using node version 18 in my package.json and the application runs perfectly. The error only occurs in the deployment.

My env code:

```
import { config } from 'dotenv'
import { z } from 'zod'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  config({ path: '.env.test', override: true })
} else {
  config()
}

const envSchema = z.object({
  NODE_ENV: z.enum(['development', 'test', 'production']).default('production'),
  DATABASE_CLIENT: z.enum(['sqlite', 'pg']),
  DATABASE_URL: z.string(),
  PORT: z.coerce.number().default(3333),
})

const _env = envSchema.safeParse(process.env)

if (_env.success === false) {
  console.error('Invalid environment variables', _env.error.format())

  throw new Error('Invalid environment variables')
}

export const env = _env.data
```

How can I fix this?